# WIA, Vista, and VB6. Does this code work?

Tags: vb6, windows-vista, camera, wia, image-scanner

Basically the constraints here are that i must use WIA because i am trying to get my scanner software to work in Windows 7 and Vista.  It would be preferable (like really preferable) if i could do this in VB6.
Now this code i have compiles and everything, however when i run it i get the error "No WIA device of the selected type is available." I'm beginning to suspect that my scanner is not WIA compatible.

Could anyone confirm that this code should work? (needs to work with any WIA device not just scanners)

```
Dim WIADia As WIA.CommonDialog
Dim Scan As WIA.DeviceManager


Set WIADia = New WIA.CommonDialog
Set Scan = WIADia.ShowSelectDevice(WIA.WiaDeviceType.UnspecifiedDeviceType, True, False)
WIADia.ShowAcquisitionWizard (Scan)
```

Thanks!

Comment: At the very least, you should remove the `(` and `)` around `Scan`. That will cause the value to be evaluated and most likely an error at that point. Which call is saying "No WIA device available"? Does it work in any other scanning application?

Comment: It does the same on my machine, but I don't have a scanner attached. I do have a webcam though....

Answer (score -1):

```
        WIA.CommonDialog WIADia;
        Device Scan;

        WIADia = new WIA.CommonDialog();
        Scan = WIADia.ShowSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.UnspecifiedDeviceType, true, false);
        WIADia.ShowAcquisitionWizard(Scan);
```

Comment: All you've done is convert to C#... Did you mean to include any more? or maybe an answer?